# React: How can I serve assets without the PUBLIC_URL appearing in the route?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a portfolio website which contains my resume. I want the route `http://localhost:3000/resume.pdf` to open my resume for people to see. The resume.pdf file is inside my public folder. Unfortunately, this does not work and I have to go to `http://localhost:3000/personal-website/resume.pdf` to actually see my resume. How can I get rid of the `/personal-website` prefix caused by the process.env.PUBLIC_URL?

My code looks like this
`<href={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/resume.pdf"}> Resume </a>`

Comment: What's the use case here? What difference does it make? Is it just a personal preference?

Can you share an image of where your public folder is located?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running apache server, you can use `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^resume.pdf personal-website/resume.pdf [L]
```